# How to create JQueryUI Draggable stacked in the same position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a droppable grid to be an icon grid. The idea is to create the draggable icons already dropped.

I couldn't create the draggable already dropped, so I mimic the dropping and put the droppable as disable while it has something.

It is working, but since I create all the draggables and droppables and then mimic the dropping, the drag elements are created in a list using a lot of space in the page. And after they are dropped, that used space still remains in the page.

What I want is to be able to create all draggable elements in a single space (stacked), so I can move it to the position I want without the need for extra space.

Here's my complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    body{
        font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
        margin: 50px;
    }
    .demoHeaders {
        margin-top: 2em;
    }
    #dialog-link {
        padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    #dialog-link span.ui-icon {
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: .2em;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }
    .draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;}
    .droppable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
    #mainContainer {width: 1220px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; background : gray;}
    .dragContainer {width: 1220px; height: 120px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to jQuery UI!</h1>

<div class="dragContainer">
    <div id="set">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mainContainer">

</div>

<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var dropGrid = [];

$(function() {  
    var l = 20;
    while(l--) {
        $("#mainContainer").append("<div id=\"droppable"+l+"\" class=\"ui-widget-content droppable\"><p>Drop here</p></div>");
        $( "#droppable"+l ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.draggable.offset({top : $(this).offset().top, left : $(this).offset().left});
                $( this ).droppable({ disabled: true });
                var old = dropGrid[$(ui.draggable).attr("id")];
                console.log("OLD: " + old);
                if(old) {
                    console.log("ENABLING");
                    $("#"+old).droppable('option', 'disabled', false);
                }
                dropGrid[$(ui.draggable).attr("id")] = $(this).attr("id");
                console.log("TEST: " + dropGrid[$(ui.draggable).attr("id")]);
            }
        });
        $( "#droppable"+l ).droppable({ hoverClass: "ui-widget-header" });
    }

    l = 15;
    while(l--) {
        $("#set").append("<div id=\"draggable"+l+"\" class=\"ui-state-highlight draggable\"><p>Drag me to my target</p></div>");
    }

    $( "#set div" ).draggable({ 
        stack: "#set div",
        revert : "invalid",
        cursor : "move"
    });

    $("#draggable3").offset({top : $("#droppable15").offset().top, left : $("#droppable15").offset().left});
    dropGrid["draggable3"] = "droppable15";
    $( "#droppable15" ).droppable({ disabled: true });

    $("#draggable4").offset({top : $("#droppable18").offset().top, left : $("#droppable18").offset().left});
    dropGrid["draggable4"] = "droppable18";
    $( "#droppable18" ).droppable({ disabled: true });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I couldn't create the draggable already dropped"*? Maybe if we fix the actual issue you won't need the work around at all..

Comment: What I mean is that when I create a draggable div, it appears in a determined position, taking space in the page. Right after that I move it to some droppable, but if I could create the draggable already dropped into the droppable the space wouldn't be used.

Comment: My idea as a whole is to create an icon grid like a desktop with grid alignment, so I can track the position of the icon and allow the user to change it as he likes. To solve this, I made this code to create a grid of droppable elements, and I want to create the user icons as draggable into this grid, allowing the user to drag this element to any other grid position in a way I can track and save.

Thank you for you comment!

Comment: Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cc2v33em/)?

Comment: Yes! That's what I was talking about! Thank you very much!

It would be better if I could create the draggables already dropped (Not using any space else), but this is a good start!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `position:absolute` so that the elements will overlap instead of taking up individual space in the ui. Apply

```
#set div{
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:80px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cc2v33em/)